# Вывод из БД в ссылки с описанием

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Есть сайт который делает выпадающие меню из БД и выводит под нужным id нужное имя, как сделать так, чтобы вместо выпадаюшего меню были, так сказать ссылки на каждый объект из БД, а рядом какое-нибудь описание(картинка, например - или брать картинку и сделать ее как ссылку) и что-бы количество объектов было не более 5-ти на странице.
Множество страниц делать не вариант т.к объектов > 500

```
echo '<input type="text" id="selectFilter" placeholder="Введи текст для поиска" />';
echo "<form method='post' action='obj.php'><select name='id'  id='filterableSelect'>";

$sql = mysql_query("select * from `obj`  order by `id`");
for ($i = 1; $i <= mysql_num_rows($sql); $i++)
{                           
    while($s=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    { 
        echo "<option value='".$s['id']."'>".$s['name']."</option>";                                                    
    }
    $sec = $s['id'];
    echo "<br>";                     
}

echo "</select><input type='submit' name='action' value='Выбрать Obj файл'></form>";
```

[image: Сайт]

Comment: ну, видимо, вместо пунктов выпадашки (echo '<option .... >') выводить ссылки (echo '<a href="...">...</a>'). в чем трудность?

Comment: @AlexandrX я понимаю,но я не знаю как сделать чтобы бралась картинка из БД с выбранным id,и по нажатию на нее она работала как ссылка которая передает     $sec = $s['id'];
а еще как сдлеать чтобы таких картинок было штук 5 на странице, потом еще штук 5  и тд

Comment: @AlexandrX мб трудности нету,я не знаю как это реализовать ,особенно вывод ограниченного количества на стр

Comment: ну брат, ты сложный вопрос задал :)  для ограничения - см. `SELECT .... LIMIT`. для вывода картинок - см. основы HTML. Подробнее чем тут http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/SELECT.html и тут http://htmlbook.ru/html/a тут врядли кто объяснит :)